# Nginx 1.25 reverse proxy throws 502 bad gateway error for 2nd domain being added for react client

Tags: reactjs, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

A `reverse proxy nginx` 1.25 was configured for `currentdomain.com` on ubuntu 20 server. Now a second domain `domain2nd.com` is being added to the nginx to host `React` client. The following configuration throws 502 bad gateway error when react client makes connection. Here is the nginx.conf:

```
server {. #for currentdomain.com which is working fine

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8545;
  }

  location /api {. ###nodejs server
    #rewrite /api/(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

  location ~ ^/(sokt|socket.io) {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  server_name currentdomain.com www.currentdomain.com;
  #

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/currentdomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Ce>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/currentdomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by >
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.currentdomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = currentdomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;

  server_name currentdomain.com www.currentdomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

#############for domain2nd.com. <<<==nginx reverse proxy throw 502 bad gateway when connecting to domain2nd.com/www.domain2nd.com from a react client

server {
   listen       80;
   server_name www.domain2nd.com domain2nd.com;

   location / { #for react client
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;  #proxy to port 3000 for react client
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }

   location /api { #route to nodejs server for react client
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   }
}
```

Here is nginx error.log:

```
2024/01/18 02:03:52 [error] 1058025#1058025: *40 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.222, server: www.domain2nd.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "www.domain2nd.com"
2024/01/18 02:03:52 [error] 1058025#1058025: *40 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.222, server: www.domain2nd.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "www.domain2nd.com", referrer: "http://www.domain2nd.com/"
2024/01/18 02:04:05 [error] 1058025#1058025: *44 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.222, server: www.domain2nd.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "domain2nd.com"
2024/01/18 02:04:05 [error] 1058025#1058025: *44 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.222, server: www.domain2nd.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "domain2nd.com", referrer: "http://domain2nd.com/"
```

Here is the CORS configuration for app.use(cors()) with nodejs:

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: `http://localhost:3000`,  //3000 is port for reactjs app. nodejs/express is running on port 5000
    credentials: true
  };
```

In develop environment, http://localhost:3000 in a browser brings up the react page successfully.

UPDATE:

Here is the server.js for nodejs 20.x:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname +'/config/.env'});
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
const {Server} = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  path: "/sokt",
  cors: {
    origin: ["https://currentdomain.com", "http://localhost"] //  for production
  }
});
app.set("io", io);
const helper = require("./lib/helper");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;  //PORT is 5000

require("./startup/routes")(app);
require("./startup/db");
require("./startup/association")();
require("./startup/accessstoragecron");
require("./models/log");
//require("./startup/testTextmsg")(); //test send text msg

//console.log("io ::: ", io);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
  socket.on('disconnect', async () => {
      console.log('disconnected event');
  });

});


httpServer.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));  //for socket.io on express
```

Comment: `netstat -tlnp` check if the 3000 port is listening for `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Surprise that `netstat -tlnp` shows no one listening to port 3000, even after `yarn build` under react's client subdirectory.

Comment: I believe `yarn build` will only build the artifact, it won't start the client. In this case, you have 2 options: #1 start the react client in development mode, so it can serve on port 3000 #2 in nginx, don't proxy pass to 127.0.0.1:3000, instead, serve the generated artifacts directly(prefered).

Comment: Hi `Qingfeng`, to serve the artifacts, do I config nginx to proxy_pass to the yarn build subdirectory? It is pretty much dynamic page for react clients which pulls data directly from the db with api calls.

Comment: If you node service not run 3000. Paste info related to it here. Info in your question has nothing to do why your node service not running on the port 3000.

Comment: After changing proxy-pass port to localhost:5000 (which is the same as nodejs port) for domain2nd, the server starts to answer connection.

Comment: It should be easier to run the reatjs in a docker container and just call the container url and port from nginx. You can use a nginx proxy manager docker container too for an easier set up. Here a simple example on how to dockerize a reactjs app. https://dev.to/karanpratapsingh/dockerize-your-react-app-4j2e

Answer (score 1):

### Context

Based on the information in your question and your comments, it seems like your current setup is

> Browser loads React app  from localhost:3000
>
> Loaded app <-> currentdomain.com (Nginx) <-proxy-> NodeJs backend
> (localhost:5000)

You would want it to be

> Browser loads React app from domain2nd.com (Nginx) <-proxy-> localhost:3000
>
> Loaded app -> currentdomain.com (Nginx) <-proxy-> NodeJs backend (localhost:5000)

Also, it looks like you are running your development environment using something like `yarn start`. It's working fine for you as it spins up a development server at `localhost:3000` on your local machine. It works with your locally running NodeJs server as it has been whitelisted in `corsOptions`.

### Probable cause of the issue

When you attempt running it with `domain2nd.com`, you are running a `yarn build` instead of `yarn start` (probably you Ctrl+C'd it before running `yarn build`). It does not start a development server at `localhost:3000`. Your current Nginx configuration expects a local development server running at port 3000 and it finds none. Hence, a 502 error.

### Option 1: Quick solution

If you would like to continue using a reverse proxy at `localhost:3000` without changing your Nginx configuration, all you need to do is keep a development server running in addition to your Nginx server instead of doing a `yarn build`. This will start sending requests from `domain2nd.com` to `localhost:3000`.

### Option 2: Best practice

`yarn build` generates static optimized artifacts which can be used by web servers like Nginx and is a recommended way to do it for non-development environments. It does not require a separate development server to run either. For this to work, your Nginx configuration for `domain2nd.com` will have to be updated as:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name www.domain2nd.com domain2nd.com;

   location / { #for react client
    # Indicate a root directory to Nginx
    root <your-code-directory>/build; # this is where yarn build dumps artifacts
    # Set index.html as starting point
    index index.html;
   }

   location /api { #route to nodejs server for react client
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   }
}
```

**Please note** that Nginx process may require specific access permissions to your `build` directory in case your Nginx service is running with a non-root user

### CORS Settings

For both the above options, you will have to add `domain2nd.com` and `www.domain2nd.com` to the list of CORS allowed domains in your `server.js` as requests will now start originating from `domain2nd.com` instead of `localhost`.